# Unable to change Gitea admin password

Tags: git, gitea

I am unable to change Gitea admin password from command prompt. I try following command.

```
gitea admin change-password --username myusername --password asecurenewpassword
```

Error message:

> models.SetEngine: Failed to connect to database: Unknown database
>   type: 2019/07/17 10:57:10 [I] XORM Log Mode: Console(Info)

Comment: Note to moderators: gitlab is on topic, just like GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter `--config` to point the exact path of gitea config.

So, if config file is located at `/etc/gitea/app.ini`, then run:

```
gitea admin change-password --username myusername --password asecurenewpassword  --config /etc/gitea/app.ini
```